# Image doesn't display in the border

Tags: javascript, css, image, border

I'm using the following code to upload profile images and it works fine, but the problem is that when i upload a picture it doesn't display in the border as it should be! Any thoughts why this happens?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>form practice</title>
 
 <!--Calculate age from dob script-->


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#dob").change(function(){
               var value = $("#dob").val();
                var dob = new Date(value);
                var today = new Date();
                var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                if(isNaN(age)) {

                // will set 0 when value will be NaN
                 age=0;

                }
                else{
                  age=age;
                }
                $('#age').val(age);

            });

        });
        </script>
  
  <!--End of Calculate age from dob script-->
  
     <!--Upload Picture Script-->
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
           $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
        $('#dummyImg').attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
});
</script>

     <!--End of Upload Picture Script-->

<style>
#dummyImg{width:100%;}
.img-block{border:2px solid cyan;
width:200px; padding: 100px;}
</style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="form2" id="form2" name="form2">

    <form action="php/form2.php" method="post" id="Personalinfo">

    <label for="fname">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Client Name..">

    <label for="lname">Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Client Lastname..">

    <label for="dob">Birthday:</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd..">

    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Client Age.."><br><br>
 
 <div class="img-block">
  <img src="dummyImg.png" id="dummyImg"  />
</div>
<label for="profilepic">Profile Picture:</label>
<input type="file" id="profilepic" name="profilepic" accept="image/*" placeholder="Profile Pic.." border="5"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submitForm2" value="Submit">


    </form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When I'm running this code on localhost the uploading procedure goes fine, but the problem is that the uploaded photo doesn't display in the border as it should be!

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem will be very useful as I'm newbie in coding.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s4z7fof8/

```
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#dummyImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("input:file").change(function (){
        console.log("File selected");
        readURL(this);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'photo doesn't display in the border', but I'm guessing that you want the border to be right next to the image, and not have the gap you have now.

If you use `inspect element` in your browser and click on the declaration of the containing `div` you'll see that the padding gets between the image and the border. If you change padding to margin in the `style` tag the border ends up right next to the image.

```
.img-block {
    border:2px solid cyan;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 100px;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response! my question was why when i upload a picture it doesn't show up into the border as it should be!

Comment: To help you understand here is the code as provided by another user and it works fine (inserting images into the border). My problem is that as i can see i followed this code with a few changes but it doesn't inserts the image into the border as it should be! Please check the link 
 to the example! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520949/display-border-above-input-image-field/45521291#45521291

Comment: I tried running the code there, but I wasn't able to upload an image. But, just to clarify, what do you mean by 'inserting the image into the border? Is it that you don't want the space between the image and the border, like in your code, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! The answer provided by the user @d2718nis works fine now! but thank you too for trying to help!